# the "closest()" method in jquery wont work

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html

so i have this html code and jquery code. And when i press a tablerows "produkter" button whith the class name "fa-products", i want to find the hidden field input that is on the same tablerow as the button you choose to click(every tablerow have a hidden field input and a "produkter button"). Then i want to save the value of the hidden field in a variable thats all can anyone help me? when i "console.log(discountId);" it responds undefiend

```
 <div class="eastSide row top-buffer col-xs-8" style="overflow:scroll; height:250px;">

    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Aktiv</th>
            <th>Skapad</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var discount in Model.DiscountList)
        {

            <tr>

                <td><input name="codeTextBox" id="codeTextBox"  value="@discount.Code" maxlength="18" /></td>

                <td><input type="checkbox" id="activeCheckBox" name="activeCheckBox" checked="@discount.Active" /></td>
                <td><input type="datetime" value="@discount.CreatedDate" readonly /></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="Radera" class="fa fa-remove" data-url="@Url.Action("DeleteDiscountCode","Discount",new { id= discount.Id})" />
                    <input type="button" value="Uppdatera" class="fa fa-update" data-url="@Url.Action("UpdateDiscount","Discount")" />
                    <input type="button" value="Produkter" class="fa fa-products" id="@discount.Id" data-url="@Url.Action("chooseProductsForDiscountCode","Discount")" />
                </td>
                <td><input id="id" type="hidden" value="@discount.Id" /></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>


</div>



<script>
 $(".fa-products").on("click", function (e) {


                var discountId =     $(event.target).closest('input[type="hidden"]').val();
                console.log(discountId);





            });
</script>
```

Comment: when i console.log(discountId);it responds undefiend @Teemu

Comment: [The docs for closest says](http://api.jquery.com/closest/): "_...get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors ..._", your "hidden" is not on the way up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will not work, because the hidden input is not the parent of the registered element.

Probably this will solve your issue: `$(event.target).closest('tr').find('input[type="hidden"]').val();`

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: Now it's better :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do search for common parent element via `closest` and then find `input` inside of the result:

```
$(".fa-products").on("click", function (e) {
    var discountId = $(event.target).closest('tr').find('input[type="hidden"]').val();
    console.log(discountId);
});
```